# Finding PyQT5 compatible with python 2.7, MySQL and mac OS

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, pyqt5

I have installed pyqt5 using home-brew on the terminal but when I run a python 2.7 idle file and import "PyQt5" it says `"ImportError: No module named PyQt5"`

Have I installed it correctly, how would I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading through the documentation ([PyQt5 docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html)) it seems, that PyQt5 is only available for Python 3 and not Python 2.

Do you have Python 3 installed on your Mac? If so, then try to import it using Python 3. If you have Python 3 not installed, you can also do it via home-brew using:

```
brew install python3
```

If you need to use Python 2.7, then you should consider using PyQt4 which seems to be compatible (haven't tested, just looked up the docs).

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is still possible to build PyQt5 for Python2 from the source.